# Counting elements in list

Tags: python, list, numpy

Let's say I have a list of customer IDs and a category of item that he buys:

[ [ID0 , 0], [ID1, 1], ... ]

A customer can appear more than once, and it is also possible that he buys the same type of item more than once.

For example, it is possible that we have [ID0, 1], [ID0, 2], [ID0, 1], [ID1, 1], ... somewhere in our list.

I want to construct a list so that list[0] = customer ID and list[1] = the most common type of item that he has bought, which means that a customerID only appears once in the list.

How do I do that?

Comment: Please show your attempts.

Comment: Sorry. All that I can think is a naive solution, to use nested loops and counters. But as you know, that is very inefficient. I'm a newbie in python so I don't really know powerful libraries that can help.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something, can you not use a dictionary for this purpose?
This basically ensures you get no duplicates, and using the max function you can get the maxiumum value. the .get() method ensures that you get a None if the key is not found.

Of course you can format the dictionary as a list, if needed.

```
data = [
       ['ID0', 1], ['ID0', 2], ['ID0', 1], ['ID1', 1],
       ['ID2', 5], ['ID5', 6]
]

dict = {}
for item in data:
    customer_id = item[0]
    current_quantity = item[1]
    #find maximum amount of what's already in dictionary vs current
    dict[customer_id] = max(current_quantity, dict.get(customer_id))
```